# SSRS reportserver? link is not working

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

This may be a small thing, but not able to find the solution.

> http://ServerName/Report_Dev/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReportName

this works, but the next one don't work

> http://ServerName/Report_Dev/reportserver?/ReportName&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Toolbar=false

do i need to configure something in the SSRS to make "reportserver?" work. 
Thanks in advance

Edited: 
I think the URL should be

> http://ServerName/Report_Dev?/ReportName&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Toolbar=false

but still this is not opening the report, instead it is going to the home page of reports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you configured the virtual directory for report server?  If the Report Manager is configured in the Report_Dev virtual directory (which I think it is, looking at the first link you shared) then I would expect to see a sibling address for report server, for example:

```
http://ServerName/ReportServer?/ReportName&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Toolbar=false
```

They are two different web applications - have a look in the SQL configuration manager.

EDIT:

As per the comment "Don't use the Report Manager URL"

Comment: My bad I am using ReportServer URl as Report Manager URl, rather then Report URL

Comment: Thanks for your help, it will be great if you add oe more line in your answer saying "Don't use Report Manager Url for this"